# Translate a parented object on the world axis of another parented object using bpy

Tags: scripting

I have an object "Cube" which is parented to an empty "Object". I have another object "Cube.001" which is parented to another empty "Object.001". Both objects and cubes have local rotation and translation. I would like to write a bpy module which can translate "Cube" on the Y axis of the "Cube.001". I believe i need to work with the matrix_world of both objects, but i am not able to proceed after that

[image]